Probability of being inside a convex n-dimensional polytop
I am currently conducting some post-grad research about wireless transmissions with uncertain transmission delays.
As part of the research, each individual transmission is modelled using a probability distribution. We call a transmission successful if and only if the actual transmission was inside a specified interval [$q_{low},q_{high}$], resulting in an $n$-dimensional box when considering $n$ transmissions.
Furthermore, we make linear constraints about multiple transmissions, i.e. saying that the sum of a set of transmissions is limited. This could be for example something like $\sum_i q_i\leq i*median$, therefore restricting the solution space even more, resulting in an $n$-dimensional convex polytop.
For the boxed approach (with no further restrictions) the formula $\prod_{i}Pr[D(i)]\in [q_{i_{low}}, q_{i_{high}}]$ can simply be used. However, of course, such a simple computation is not possible for the more complex case.
Since I am not the most profounded person when it comes to numerical analysis, I wanted to ask whether someone knows a good applicable method to compute the (approximate) probability of a single data point being inside the polyhedron, especially in high dimensions.
Thanks in advance for any help!

This is by definition the volume of the polyhedron with respect to the given probability measure. I doubt that much can be said without knowing more about the used probabilty distributions. Also, I don't understand the intent behind the formula with the median. Why is there an $i$ on the right hand side?

@HenrikRüping the probability distribution is empirically gathered through experiments and can mostly be described as a uni-modal heavy tailed distribution.
About the formula with the median: This is something specific to the application. The idea is that each individual transmission $q_i$ may take very long (outlier) but the sum of all transmissions may be very close to the mean (multiplied by the number of transmissions)
